# Invoking OLE in C# using OleCreateFromFile returns 0x800004016 Use of Ole1 services requiring DDE windows is disabled

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, ole

I am trying to make use of the c# converted code over at this post:
[Releasing an OLE IStorage file handle in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688054/releasing-an-ole-istorage-file-handle-in-c-sharp)

In this post, the OP looks to have created a custom class OLE32 which uses pinvoke to declare the IStorage and IOleObject interfaces, as well as the different methods. I have done the same thing. My issue is that when I try and call OLE32.OleCreateFromFile, the return value I get is -2147467242 .

This return value converts to 0x80004016 in hex, which, according to everything I can find, is the following error:

Use of Ole1 services requiring DDE windows is disabled

The method should spit out an IOleObject, but instead pOle is null and the methods following this fail.

Does anybody know why I might be getting this error and how I can fix it? Below I have included complete code as well as my OLE32 class.

The method:

```
   public static string ExportOleFile(string _inputFileName, string oleOutputFileName, string emfOutputFileName)
    {
        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();

        string newInput = MultibyteToUnicodeNETOnly(_inputFileName, 1252); 


        OLE32.IStorage storage;
        var result = OLE32.StgCreateStorageEx(oleOutputFileName,
            Convert.ToInt32(OLE32.STGM.STGM_READWRITE | OLE32.STGM.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | OLE32.STGM.STGM_CREATE | OLE32.STGM.STGM_TRANSACTED),
            Convert.ToInt32(OLE32.STGFMT.STGFMT_DOCFILE),
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref OLE32.IID_IStorage,
            out storage
        );

        resultString.AppendLine("CreateStorageEx Result: " + result.ToString());

       var CLSID_NULL = Guid.Empty;

        OLE32.IOleObject pOle;
        result = OLE32.OleCreateFromFile(
            ref CLSID_NULL,
            _inputFileName,
            ref OLE32.IID_IOleObject,
            (uint)OLE32.OLERENDER.OLERENDER_NONE,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null,
            storage,
            out pOle
        );

        resultString.AppendLine("OleCreateFromFile Result: " + result.ToString());
        try
        {

            result = OLE32.OleRun(pOle);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultString.AppendLine(ex.ToString());
            return resultString.ToString();
        }

        resultString.AppendLine("OleRun Result: " + result.ToString());

        try
        {

            IntPtr unknownFromOle = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(pOle);
            IntPtr unknownForDataObj;
            Marshal.QueryInterface(unknownFromOle, ref OLE32.IID_IDataObject, out unknownForDataObj);
            var pdo = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(unknownForDataObj) as System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject;

            var fetc = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC();

            fetc.cfFormat = (short)OLE32.CLIPFORMAT.CF_ENHMETAFILE;
            fetc.dwAspect = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT;
            fetc.lindex = -1;
            fetc.ptd = IntPtr.Zero;
            fetc.tymed = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYMED.TYMED_ENHMF;

            var stgm = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM();
            stgm.unionmember = IntPtr.Zero;
            stgm.tymed = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYMED.TYMED_ENHMF;
            pdo.GetData(ref fetc, out stgm);

            var hemf = GDI32.CopyEnhMetaFile(stgm.unionmember, emfOutputFileName);
            storage.Commit((int)OLE32.STGC.DEFAULT);

            pOle.Close(0);
            GDI32.DeleteEnhMetaFile(stgm.unionmember);
            GDI32.DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultString.AppendLine(ex.ToString());
            return resultString.ToString();
        }


        return resultString.ToString();

    }
```

OLE32.cs:

```
  public static class OLE32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct STGOPTIONS
        {
            ushort usVersion;
            ushort reserved;
            ulong ulSectorSize;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string pwcsTemplateFile;
        };

        public enum OLERENDER
        {
            OLERENDER_NONE = 0,
            OLERENDER_DRAW = 1,
            OLERENDER_FORMAT = 2,
            OLERENDER_ASIS = 3
        }

        internal enum CLIPFORMAT : int
        {
            CF_TEXT = 1,
            CF_BITMAP = 2,
            CF_METAFILEPICT = 3,
            CF_SYLK = 4,
            CF_DIF = 5,
            CF_TIFF = 6,
            CF_OEMTEXT = 7,
            CF_DIB = 8,
            CF_PALETTE = 9,
            CF_PENDATA = 10,
            CF_RIFF = 11,
            CF_WAVE = 12,
            CF_UNICODETEXT = 13,
            CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14,
            CF_HDROP = 15,
            CF_LOCALE = 16,
            CF_MAX = 17,
            CF_OWNERDISPLAY = 0x80,
            CF_DSPTEXT = 0x81,
            CF_DSPBITMAP = 0x82,
            CF_DSPMETAFILEPICT = 0x83,
            CF_DSPENHMETAFILE = 0x8E,
        }

        internal enum STGFMT : int
        {
            STGFMT_STORAGE = 0,
            STGFMT_FILE = 3,
            STGFMT_ANY = 4,
            STGFMT_DOCFILE = 5
        }

        [Flags]
        internal enum STGM : int
        {
            STGM_READ = 0x0,
            STGM_WRITE = 0x1,
            STGM_READWRITE = 0x2,
            STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE = 0x40,
            STGM_SHARE_DENY_READ = 0x30,
            STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE = 0x20,
            STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x10,
            STGM_PRIORITY = 0x40000,
            STGM_CREATE = 0x1000,
            STGM_CONVERT = 0x20000,
            STGM_FAILIFTHERE = 0x0,
            STGM_DIRECT = 0x0,
            STGM_TRANSACTED = 0x10000,
            STGM_NOSCRATCH = 0x100000,
            STGM_NOSNAPSHOT = 0x200000,
            STGM_SIMPLE = 0x8000000,
            STGM_DIRECT_SWMR = 0x400000,
            STGM_DELETEONRELEASE = 0x4000000
        }

        public enum STGC
        {
            DEFAULT = 0,
            OVERWRITE = 1,
            ONLYIFCURRENT = 2,
            DANGEROUSLYCOMMITMERELYTODISKCACHE = 4,
            CONSOLIDATE = 8
        }


        public static Guid IID_IDataObject = new Guid("{0000010e-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

        public static Guid IID_IOleObject = new Guid("{00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

        public static Guid IID_IStorage = new Guid("0000000B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");



        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int StgCreateStorageEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string
           pwcsName, int grfMode, int stgfmt, int grfAttrs, IntPtr pStgOptions, IntPtr reserved2, ref Guid riid,
           out IStorage ppObjectOpen);


        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int OleCreateFromFile([In] ref Guid rclsid,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszFileName, ref Guid riid,
           uint renderopt, IntPtr pFormatEtc, IOleClientSite pClientSite,
           IStorage pStg, out IOleObject ppvObj);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int OleRun([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pUnknown);


        [ComImport]
        [Guid("00000118-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IOleClientSite
        {
            void SaveObject();
            void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, ref object ppmk);
            void GetContainer(ref object ppContainer);
            void ShowObject();
            void OnShowWindow(bool fShow);
            void RequestNewObjectLayout();
        }




        [ComImport]
        [Guid("0000000b-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IStorage
        {
            void CreateStream(
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsName,
                /* [in] */ uint grfMode,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved1,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved2,
                /* [out] */ out IStream ppstm);

            void OpenStream(
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsName,
                /* [unique][in] */ IntPtr reserved1,
                /* [in] */ uint grfMode,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved2,
                /* [out] */ out IStream ppstm);

            void CreateStorage(
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsName,
                /* [in] */ uint grfMode,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved1,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved2,
                /* [out] */ out IStorage ppstg);

            void OpenStorage(
                /* [string][unique][in] */ string pwcsName,
                /* [unique][in] */ IStorage pstgPriority,
                /* [in] */ uint grfMode,
                /* [unique][in] */ IntPtr snbExclude,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved,
                /* [out] */ out IStorage ppstg);

            void CopyTo(
                /* [in] */ uint ciidExclude,
                /* [size_is][unique][in] */ Guid rgiidExclude, // should this be an array?
                /* [unique][in] */ IntPtr snbExclude,
                /* [unique][in] */ IStorage pstgDest);

            void MoveElementTo(
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsName,
                /* [unique][in] */ IStorage pstgDest,
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsNewName,
                /* [in] */ uint grfFlags);

            void Commit(
                /* [in] */ uint grfCommitFlags);

            void Revert();

            void EnumElements(
                /* [in] */ uint reserved1,
                /* [size_is][unique][in] */ IntPtr reserved2,
                /* [in] */ uint reserved3,
                /* [out] */ out IEnumSTATSTG ppenum);

            void DestroyElement(
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsName);

            void RenameElement(
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsOldName,
                /* [string][in] */ string pwcsNewName);

            void SetElementTimes(
                /* [string][unique][in] */ string pwcsName,
                /* [unique][in] */ System.Runtime.InteropServices.FILETIME pctime,
                /* [unique][in] */ System.Runtime.InteropServices.FILETIME patime,
                /* [unique][in] */ System.Runtime.InteropServices.FILETIME pmtime);

            void SetClass(
                /* [in] */ Guid clsid);

            void SetStateBits(
                /* [in] */ uint grfStateBits,
                /* [in] */ uint grfMask);

            void Stat(
                /* [out] */ out System.Runtime.InteropServices.STATSTG pstatstg,
                /* [in] */ uint grfStatFlag);

        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IOleObject
        {
            void SetClientSite(IOleClientSite pClientSite);
            void GetClientSite(ref IOleClientSite ppClientSite);
            void SetHostNames(object szContainerApp, object szContainerObj);
            void Close(uint dwSaveOption);
            void SetMoniker(uint dwWhichMoniker, object pmk);
            void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
            void InitFromData(IDataObject pDataObject, bool fCreation, uint dwReserved);
            void GetClipboardData(uint dwReserved, ref IDataObject ppDataObject);
            void DoVerb(uint iVerb, uint lpmsg, object pActiveSite, uint lindex, uint hwndParent, uint lprcPosRect);
            void EnumVerbs(ref object ppEnumOleVerb);
            void Update();
            void IsUpToDate();
            void GetUserClassID(uint pClsid);
            void GetUserType(uint dwFormOfType, uint pszUserType);
            void SetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
            void GetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
            void Advise(object pAdvSink, uint pdwConnection);
            void Unadvise(uint dwConnection);
            void EnumAdvise(ref object ppenumAdvise);
            void GetMiscStatus(uint dwAspect, uint pdwStatus);
            void SetColorScheme(object pLogpal);
        };

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("0000000d-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IEnumSTATSTG
        {
            // The user needs to allocate an STATSTG array whose size is celt.
            [PreserveSig]
            uint
            Next(
            uint celt,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out]
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.STATSTG[] rgelt,
            out uint pceltFetched
            );

            void Skip(uint celt);

            void Reset();

            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            IEnumSTATSTG Clone();
        }


        [ComImport, Guid("0000000c-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IStream
        {
            void Read([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] byte[] pv, uint cb, out uint pcbRead);
            void Write([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] byte[] pv, uint cb, out uint pcbWritten);
            void Seek(long dlibMove, uint dwOrigin, out long plibNewPosition);
            void SetSize(long libNewSize);
            void CopyTo(IStream pstm, long cb, out long pcbRead, out long pcbWritten);
            void Commit(uint grfCommitFlags);
            void Revert();
            void LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, uint dwLockType);
            void UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, uint dwLockType);
            void Stat(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.STATSTG pstatstg, uint grfStatFlag);
            void Clone(out IStream ppstm);
        }


        [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("0000010E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        public interface IDataObject
        {
            void GetData([In] ref FORMATETC format, out STGMEDIUM medium);
            void GetDataHere([In] ref FORMATETC format, ref STGMEDIUM medium);
            [PreserveSig]
            int QueryGetData([In] ref FORMATETC format);
            [PreserveSig]
            int GetCanonicalFormatEtc([In] ref FORMATETC formatIn, out FORMATETC formatOut);
            void SetData([In] ref FORMATETC formatIn, [In] ref STGMEDIUM medium, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool release);
            IEnumFORMATETC EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR direction);
            [PreserveSig]
            int DAdvise([In] ref FORMATETC pFormatetc, ADVF advf, IAdviseSink adviseSink, out int connection);
            void DUnadvise(int connection);
            [PreserveSig]
            int EnumDAdvise(out IEnumSTATDATA enumAdvise);
        }











    }
```

Comment: could you please add the imports or whole code somewhere? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the code, after adding the missing declarations I could run it up to pdo.GetData() call on both .NET 3.5 and 4.5.  I didn't have the correct kind of input file to continue beyond that.

There's only one decent explanation for the 0x80004016 error code.  This will occur if the thread that you run this code has called [OleInitializeEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE option.  .NET does not do this.  I have to therefore guess that the thread got started by native code and transitioned into this managed code.  It fits the kind of code, this would normally be written in C++.

You will need to hunt down that OleInitializeEx call and change it.  If that's difficult then you could consider starting your own thread to run this code so it is not affected by the bad state of the calling native thread.

Comment: Thankyou for your response Hans!

I will try and dispell your need to guess by explaining some more about the environment: 
I am intending to run this as a Web Service. It is on .NET 3.5. It starts and lives it's entire life as managed code. Is it possible that SOMETHING somewhere in perhaps IIS, my web service configuration, or a setting on the server is contributing to the COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE option being set?

Comment: Your answer led me down the right path. I started a new thread and immediately called CoUninitialize();. After that I called CoInitializeEx((System.IntPtr)null, OLE32.CoInit.ApartmentThreaded); and it all worked perfectly.

Comment: Depending on the code, one other solution to this problem is simply to add an STAThread attribute on the Main entry point function.