# Emending PDF files into OpenXML WordprocessingML

Tags: c#, pdf, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I am strugling with Open XML SDK and embedding pdf files into a docx file.

1. I do not want to use automation
2. I am able to create *.bin files from everything except from *.pdf ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701696/invoking-ole-in-c-sharp-through-olecreatefromfile-does-not-work-for-pdf-files))

Anyone has experience with this? From what I've gathered you must create a *.bin file in order to embedd any file into Word *.docx document (except images). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for pdf not working was in fact in acrobat reader. 
When Ive installed older version (or did not have AR installed at all), it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a pure C# solution, you could consider the commercial product [docx4j OLE Helper](http://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products) IKVM'd.

Disclosure: I wrote it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but I am looking for non-commercial solution/help. Ive got pretty far. What I dont get is, why the *.pdf files are a problem and the other file extensions not.